# Why OP_DUP instead of providing the PubKey twice in P2PKH?

Tags: script, p2pkh

We know that a P2PKH script looks as follows:

```
scriptPubKey: OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <PubKeyHash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
scriptSig: <Signature> <PubKey>
```

Since full nodes are maintaing UTXO sets, wouldn't it save space to omit the `OP_DUP` and have the user provide their public key twice instead, like so? And would that create any sort of security issues?

```
scriptPubKey: OP_HASH160 <PubKeyHash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
scriptSig: <Signature> <PubKey> <PubKey>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, that would not be secure. Imagine an output with scriptPubkey `OP_HASH160 <hash(P1)> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG`. Now anyone can spend such an output by generating their own key `P2`, and spending with scriptSig `<sig with P2> <P2> <P1>`.

Comment: But the attacker doesn't know `P1`. So that would require the attacker to compute the pubkey `P1` from `hash(P1)`. Isn't that (practically) impossible since the hash function is preimage-resistant?

Comment: The attacker does know if they are a miner. They can look at a legitimate transaction and substitute their own key. You cannot assume that anything except the private key is private.

Comment: Follow-up question moved to https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/116509/a-question-about-the-role-of-op-dup-in-the-p2pkh-transaction-specification-an